# Is it possible to turn off extended insert by pgsql and neo4j dumps?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, neo4j, dump

I read here that it makes versioned dumps easier to read if I turn off extended inserts. This is a MySQL feature. Is it possible to do the same by PgSQL and Neo4j databases?

According to this article: https://viget.com/extend/backup-your-database-in-git it is a good practice to make full dumps and version them in git. I discussed this with others, and according to them using **incremental backup** instead is a much better solution. Since pgsql and neo4j both support incremental backup, I won't really need this extended insert feature.

Comment: Wdym by "extended inserts" regarding Neo4j? Never heard of this.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Ohh I forgot to add the link, or somebody removed it. Extended insert means that you insert every row in a single insert statement instead of many separate insert statements. By neo4j you add the whole graph in a single cypher statement. (If that is possible. I am new to neo4j, but I like it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the feature in Neo4j being closest to "extended inserts" is the `LOAD CSV` command, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html.

Another approach is pass in your data as parameter with a list value and use `UNWIND`:

```
UNWIND {values} AS v
CREATE (:WhateverLabel {value: v})
```

The parameters here are:

```
{ "values": ["val1", "val2", "val3"] }
```

You can use `UNWIND` even for importing data from JSON, see http://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/.

Comment: By pgsql according to the manual: https://www.commandprompt.com/ppbook/x17860 we need to use `pg_dump` with the `--inserts` attribute. Btw. I edited the question, I don't really need this, I was not aware that we have incremental backup, so I wanted to version full backups with git.